# Namespace não funciona no php 5.5

Tags: php, classes, namespace

Estou fazendo um sistema simples usando php com estrutura mvc e quero usar o namespace, porem, da erro informando que não encontra a classe Data.

Erro: 
Fatal error: Class 'Config\Database\Data' not found in /home/andre/www/mvc-mercado/controller/index.controller.php on line 8

Arquivo da view:

```
<?php
include 'controller/index.controller.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> ....
```

Arquivo index.controller.php que da o erro em new DB():

```
<?php
use Config\Database\Data as DB;

class IndexController {

    public function __construct() {
        // instancia base de dados
        $database = new DB(); 
    }

}

new IndexController();
```

Arquivo data.config.php

```
<?php 
namespace Config\Database;

class Data {
     public $dbcon;

    public function __construct() {
        // abre conexão com o banco
        $this->dbcon = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mercado user=silva password=12345");

    }

    public function __destruct() {
       // fecha conexão com o banco
       pg_close($this->dbcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Meu comentário não tem relação com o erro da pergunta... No MVC não é a `view` quem carrega o *controller*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois você não está dando [include](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php) ou [require_once](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require-once.php), por exemplo, no arquivo index.php.

Uma das formas para trabalhar com estruturas no PHP, é utilizar a função [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php). Dessa forma você poderá dar os include de forma "automática".

Uma outra forma também. É trabalhar com o [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).
Com o composer, você poderá trabalhar com namespace mais facilmente.

Dica: Utilize o padrão [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) para trabalhar com namespaces.